# Qlik - SQL load statement with stored procedure and input parameters

Tags: sql-server, qlikview, qliksense

Trying to load data from a SQL Server stored procedure, this works fine for other procedures but does not want to work in this instance.

```
Load *;
Sql Exec [Report].[UspResults_SalesOrderKPI] @Company = '10' , 
@RedTagType = 'Q' , 
@RedTagUse = '' ;
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I cannot see it.

The final code I will be using will be something like the below.

```
RawSysOrders:
Load StockDescription As Product
,CustomerPoNumber As PO
,SalesOrder As PBL_Ref
,AcceptedDate
,ActualDeliveryDate As ActualShipDate
,Null() As Confirmation
,PlannedDeliverDate As ProposedShipDate
,Null() As RevisedShipDate1
,Null() As RevisedShipDate2
,Null() As RevisedShipDate3
,OrderQty As Qty
,StockCode As Code
,Null() As Volume
,Job As Batch
,CustomerName As DeliveredTo
,CustomerName As SoldTo
,Null() As PaymentTerms
,ApplyMap('Map_SOPrices',SalesOrder&'_'&SalesOrderLine,0) As GBP
,0 As USD
,0 As Euro
,1 As USDRate
,1 As EuroRate
,0 As ShippingCost
,If(ActualDeliveryDate<=PlannedDeliverDate,'Yes','No') As ShipDateMet
,DaysDiff As DaysOVer
,DispatchComments As NotesProblems
,Year(EntrySystemDate) as File;
where Year(EntrySystemDate)>=2016;
Sql Exec [BlackBox].[Report].[UspResults_SalesOrderKPI] @Company = '10' ,
@RedTagType = 'Q' ,
@RedTagUse = 'Qlik Sense > Product KPIs';
```

Comment: What does "does not want to work in this instance" mean? Are you getting an error, does no data come back, or does your computer burst into flames? It is generally good to include what undesirable behavior you are getting, or rather how the current behaviour is different from what you want.

Comment: is this stored procedure doing data modifications and possibly not setting "SET NOCOUNT ON" at the top, causing QlikView to get confused on the results?

Comment: @NamelessOne By does not work I mean just that, it doesn't throw up any error messages and it doesn't load any data.

Comment: @BruceDunwiddie just tried removing the nocount on from the procedure and this doesn't seem to have any impact, still no response from Qlik - it pauses as it gets to that part of the script but not error messages are showing

Comment: @BruceDunwiddie thanks for putting me on the trail of the nocount!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the SQL code, I now believe I have resolved the issue.

Qlik does not handle SQL row counts well, at the beginning of my sql query I had an insert causing a row count of 1 row being affected.

In order to address this, I set

```
nocount on
```

at the beginning of the query, in addition I had to set

```
nocount off
```

before returning the data.